# C++ blocking queue can't poll current data

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have faced an odd situation.
I have a android app which calls C++ code.
In C++ code, I have two thread one is putting data into a blocking queue and another thread is taking data out of blocking queue.
The data structure is like:

```
typedef struct {
    int len;
    char* data;
} myStruct;
```

Every time I will put a pointer of `myStruct` into the queue and get this pointer out of the queue.
    But sometime I will get a very big len from the data. like the log file I showed below:

```
Put Log Length: 128
Take Log Length: 128
Put Log Length: 171
Take Log Length: 171
Put Log Length: 73
Take Log Length: 73
Put Length: 99
Put Length: 72
Put Length: 124
Take Log Length: 72
......
Take Log Length: 2047249896
```

My Blocking Queue code is list below:

```
#include "BlockingQueue.h"

template<typename T>
void BlockingQueue<T>::put(const T& task)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    q.push_back( task );
    isEmpty.notify_all();
}

template<typename T>
T BlockingQueue<T>::take()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    isEmpty.wait(lock, [this]{return !q.empty(); });
    T front( q.front() );
    q.pop_front();
    return front;
}

template<typename T>
bool BlockingQueue<T>::empty()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    return q.empty();
}
```

Comment: Do not use `typedef struct { ... } foobar;`, it's evil. Especially in c++.

Comment: @cui You didn't write anything about what is the `char*` field and how it is managed. I guess the problem is related to that.

Comment: I am surpsied that code works. It should be deadlocking on mtx, since you are trying to aquire it twice.

Comment: @SergeyA - what makes you think that?

Comment: Not seeing that, @SergeyA . OP has two threads and unless they're really dumb, and it doesn't look like they are, take and put are probably in different threads.  I'm also not nearly enough information to be of much help here. Is the get of the queue size for the output also mutex-protected?

Comment: @cui - the problem doesn't seem to be in the posted code. Post the remaining part to get help.

Comment: @cui, because your `empty` is locking mtx. But by the time it is called mtx is already locked, because you just returned from wait on conditional variable.

Comment: @user4581301, because empty() tries to lock mtx - which was already locked because return from conditional variable wait locks mutex.

Comment: @SergeyA That would require `BlockingQueue` to have a member `BlockingQueue q;`, and that would be exceptionally hard to compile. I suspect `q` is just a good ol' `std::queue` or `std::vector` (and if not, why?)

Comment: @user4581301, some of us is confused. I am ready to admit it is me, but what am I missing? mtx looks to be a member of BlockingQueue. `isEmpty` is using a lock on it, upon rerturning mtx is guaranteed to be locked. After that wake up, `empty()` is called on the same object, and it locks the same mutex again. How is it not a deadlock?

Comment: @SergeyA I believe `std::queue::empty` (or `std::vector::empty`) is being called, not `BlockingQueue::empty` because for `q.empty` to call `BlockingQueue::empty` and lock the mutex again, `q` must be of type `BlockingQueue`, which means `BlockingQueue` includes a member of type `BlockingQueue` which cannot compile.